# Large SVG files that are generated dynamically on an AJAX request are not loading properly in IE9

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have an application which has lot of controls and it uses AJAX to get some client side properties like Height and Width following which the Server generates a Large SVG map and returns a response. In case of the response I am unable to load the response SVG file(whose size is 14 MB) as there are no events that fire at the time when response arrives( I tried using DOMContentLoaded and OnLoad but had no luck). I ran into errors when I tried accessing the elements of SVG in javascript which I presume that the DOM is not yet ready. How do I ensure that the large SVG File is loaded. Is there an event which I can hook up to as and when the DOM is ready in case of dynamically  generated SVG file?
Steps that I took to resolve the problem(but no luck)
 I tried generating a clone of the response SVG in JavaScript but had no luck as again I got an exception when I tried accessing one of the elements of SVG. I need some suggestions on how to load relatively Large SVG files in IE9 using Javascript(any events?) as I have been able to successfully load these files in Chrome and FireFox.

A small piece of example code to illustrate the problem after the use of SVGLoad event.

```
   var SVG=document.getElementById('gwmroot');
   SVG.addEventListener("SVGLoad","LoadSVG",false);
   function LoadSVG()
    {
      var _gwmcore.svgDoc=document;
     }
```

In the above code the SVG file is present in the document object and it comes dynamically in response to an Ajax request following which a call back happens to a javascript file which contains the above code. I am not able to call the LoadSVG function somehow. _gwmcore is a global object which will have methods and properties to process the svg document.

Thanks in advance
Phaneendra

Answer (score 0):

With SVG you're looking for an [SVGLoad event](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html#LoadEvent). It happens to be mapped to an attribute called load but if you're using addEventListener it's SVGLoad you need to look for and not load. E.g.

```
rootElement.addEventListener("SVGLoad", handler, useCapture)
```

Another gotcha for SVG is that SVGLoad events don't go to the window object so you can't do window.addEventListener as you can with html.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will try using SVGLoad

Comment: Thanks @Robert.I used SVGLoad event and i observed that it works randomly. In the first application run it worked well but in the subsequent run or when I try to refresh the page it doesn't fire. Any hack on this?

Comment: I added a small piece of code where in used SVGLoad. Is it fine?

Comment: What's gwmroot? Where's the ajax that loads the document?

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. "gwmroot" is the ID of the root element of the SVG document. The SVG document from an AJAX response is saved into a temporary cache directory and following which a map player(HTML embed tag) is created which will try to load the SVG and the Javascript file that parses the SVG document has the logic that I provided as a sample code in the question